# Typo3 extension configuration

Tags: typo3-8.x, typo3-extensions

I have installed typo3 extension `"cookieman"`. The documentation says it comes with 2 static templates. Include the static TypoScript “Cookieman” in your root template or reference the necessary files in your site package. what is the location of a root template? and what is the syntax to include something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first: be clear what `Template` means in this context.
there are multiple kinds of `template` in TYPO3.

There are HTML-templates which define the structure of parts of the output. That could be Fluid-templates or the older marker-based templates.

Then there are records which contain the `typoscript` configuration which also are called `templates`.

This typoscript-templates are meant. As the typoscript templates can be stored in each page of your page tree, which are concatenated, you have a root-template propably in the root-page of your website. (the added ts-template are called `extension-templates`as they extend the basic configuration).

These records have a field for additional templates from TYPO3 extensions which are called `static templates` as they come from an extension and are never changed (never change any file from an extension inside the extension folders!!! you always can override the values).

Otherwise you can use explicit include statements in a typoscript configuration. The include statement was invented in TYPO3 4.6 and has changed it's syntax slightly until now. In the [online-manual](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/8.7/en-us/ApiOverview/TypoScriptSyntax/Syntax/Includes.html) you can select your version to see syntax of your TYPO3 version.